# Can a smooth manifold be realised as the image of a smooth function?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds, embeddings

Consider, $M$, a smooth $m$ dimensional submanifold of $\mathbf R^n$. Does there exist a smooth map $X: \mathbf{R}^m\to\mathbf R^n$ such that $M=X(\mathbf R^m)$?

$X$ may have points at which the Jacobian is singular, which means that $M$ doesn't have to be diffeomorphic to $\mathbf{R}^m$. Furthermore, the stereographic map shows that there exists a smooth map between manifolds of different topology, so that $M$ and $\mathbf{R}^m$ apparently don't even have to be homoeomorphic. This then raises the question whether any $M$ can be represented thus.

Comment: If the only condition you put on $X$ is being smooth (and $M$ being connected I guess), then you can give $M$ a complete Riemannian metric, and then the exponential map based at any point of $M$ gives you a surjective map $\mathbb{R}^m\to M$ (see for example theorem 2.7 of Do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry")

Comment: @SaúlRM Why isn't this an answer?

Comment: Crossposted to math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4540286/can-a-smooth-manifold-be-realised-as-the-image-of-a-smooth-function

Comment: @dennis because I thought maybe you were thinking of adding some extra condition about $X$, but if not I will post it as an answer

Comment: E.g. for m=2 consider a bouquet $B$ of countably many balloons with their strands, like those they sell at the amusement parks. One can easily map $\mathbb R^2$ smoothly onto $B$, and then $B$ smoothly onto any 2-dimensional connected manifold $M$ with countable atlas - just map the base of the bouquet to a base point of $M$, each balloon to a domain of a chart, and each strand to a suitable connecting path.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My comment turned answer:

Any smooth $m$-manifold $M$ admits a complete Riemannian metric (for example, as [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/18851/172802) says, any manifold embeds into some Euclidean space as a closed subset by Whitney embedding theorem).

So if we endow any connected smooth manifold $M$ with a complete metric and choose any point $p\in M$, then the exponential map $exp_p:T_pM\to M$ gives a smooth map (Prop 5.7c of [1]) which is surjective, because any two points in $M$ are joined by a geodesic (Cor 6.15 of [1]).

[1]: John M. Lee. *Riemannian Manifolds. An introduction to curvature*. Springer, 1997.